# How to pass stripe token to server using angular 4

Tags: stripe-payments

I have following code in Node js:

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_bW0EUBWHWjWRdNzwxjIqaz7C");

const token = request.body.stripeToken; // Using Express

const charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 999,
  currency: 'usd',
  description: 'Example charge',
  source: token,
})
```

How to do this in angular 4?

Comment: Is your question how to pass the token to your Node.JS server using Angular? Or how to implement the code you show in Angular? (which is not possible)